# UE4 - How do I get actors of an array to follow the previous actor like in Snake?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am new to C++ and even newer to UE4.

I am trying to create a Snake game but I am having trouble getting the body segments of the snake to move like they should in Snake. Like a train of actors. How do I get the body to move like a train/snake in the Snake game?

I've made a gif to try and show the problem (sorry if it is too small).[Snake segment movement problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WgCa.gif)

The green actor is the Snake's head and the yellow actors are the segments that spawn (currently when I press space bar).

I can post code snipets if that helps?

The github repo is here: https://github.com/joeyisplaying/SnakeGame/tree/dev-branch/Source/SnakeGame

Comment: Consider in Snake game, only the head and tail segments move.  Most of the body segments don't actually move, they stay in the same spot.  So, draw the head in a new location, replace old head with a body segment; Likewise, erase the tail segment, then replace the last body segment with the tail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! For anyone having this problem, I managed to find a really simple solution in a video on YouTube for this. My code now looks like this:

```
    void ASnake::UpdateTailSegmentLoc()
{
    if(!TailSegment)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(TailSegment)
    {
        for (int32 i = 0; i < TailSegmentArray.Num(); i++)
        {
            const FVector CurrentSectionLoc = TailSegmentArray[i]->GetActorLocation();
            TailSegmentArray[i]->SetActorLocation(PreviousTailSegmentLoc);
            PreviousTailSegmentLoc = CurrentSectionLoc;
        }
    }
}
```

The tick looks like this now:

```
    // Called every frame
void ASnake::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    PreviousTailSegmentLoc = SnakeHead->GetComponentLocation();
    
    if(!MovementDirection.IsZero())
    {
        const FVector NewLocation = SnakeHead->GetRelativeLocation() + (MovementDirection * DeltaTime * SnakeHeadSpeed);
        SnakeHead->SetRelativeLocation(NewLocation);

        UpdateTailSegmentLoc();
    }
}
```

The YouTube video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8s86k6JUl8